# Error building Oracle client 11g R2 on RHEL 5.5

Tags: rhel, compiling, software-installation, oracle-database

We are trying to install oracle 11g R2 64 bit in Rhel 5.5 machine ( 64 bit ). Kernel version is 2.6.18-194.el5. We are getting the below error while installation.

```
error in  invoking target 'mkldflags ntcontab.o nnfgt.o' of makefile '/home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/network/lib/ins_net_client.mk'.
See '/home/oracle/oraInventory/logs/installAction2013-09-03_04-52-05PM.log' for details.
```

We have installed all necessary library packages.

```
binutils-2.17.50.0.6-14.el5.x86_64
compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-61.x86_64
compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-61.i386
elfutils-libelf-0.137-3.el5.x86_64
elfutils-libelf-0.137-3.el5.i386
elfutils-libelf-devel-static-0.137-3.el5.x86_64
elfutils-libelf-devel-static-0.137-3.el5.i386 
elfutils-libelf-devel-0.137-3.el5.x86_64
elfutils-libelf-devel-0.137-3.el5.i386
gcc-4.1.2-48.el5.x86_64
gcc-c++-4.1.2-48.el5.x86_64
glibc-2.5-49.x86_64
glibc-2.5-49.i686
glibc-common-2.5-49.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.5-49.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.5-49.i386
glibc-headers-2.5-49.x86_64
ksh-20100202-1.el5.x86_64
libaio-0.3.106-5.x86_64
libaio-0.3.106-5.i386
libaio-devel-0.3.106-5.x86_64
libaio-devel-0.3.106-5.i386
libgcc-4.1.2-48.el5.x86_64
libgcc-4.1.2-48.el5.i386
libstdc++-4.1.2-48.el5.x86_64
libstdc++-4.1.2-48.el5.i386 
libstdc++44-devel-4.4.0-6.el5.x86_64
libstdc++44-devel-4.4.0-6.el5.i386
libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-48.el5.x86_64 
libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-48.el5.i386
```

make is already installed:

```
make-3.81-3.el5.x86_64
```

Contents of log file:

```
INFO: Calling Query fileQueries10.1.0.3.0  exists

filename = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/rdbms/lib/libknlopt.a
INFO: Query Returned: false
INFO: Calling Action unixActions10.2.0.3.0  registerForMake
        installMakePath = /usr/bin/make
        installMakeFileName = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/network/lib/ins_nau.mk
        installTarget = ioklist
        installArguments = ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0
        undoMakeFileName = null
        undoTarget = null
        undoArguments = null
        logFile = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/install/make.log
        progMsg = Linking Adapters

INFO: Calling Action unixActions10.2.0.3.0  registerForMake
        installMakePath = /usr/bin/make
        installMakeFileName = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/network/lib/ins_nau.mk
        installTarget = iokinit
        installArguments = ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0
        undoMakeFileName = null
        undoTarget = null
        undoArguments = null
        logFile = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/install/make.log
        progMsg = Linking Adapters

INFO: Calling Action unixActions10.2.0.3.0  registerForMake
        installMakePath = /usr/bin/make
        installMakeFileName = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/network/lib/ins_nau.mk
        installTarget = iokdstry
        installArguments = ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0
        undoMakeFileName = null
        undoTarget = null
        undoArguments = null
        logFile = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/install/make.log
        progMsg = Linking Adapters

INFO: Linking 'Oracle Database Utilities 11.2.0.3.0 '
INFO: Linking 'Oracle Database Utilities 11.2.0.3.0 '
INFO: 9/3/13 4:54:07 PM IST: Starting install Link Phase of component Oracle Database Utilities
INFO: Calling Action unixActions10.2.0.3.0  registerForMake
        installMakePath = /usr/bin/make
        installMakeFileName = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk
        installTarget = utilities
        installArguments = ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0
        undoMakeFileName = null
        undoTarget = null
        undoArguments = null
        logFile = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/install/make.log
        progMsg = Linking Utilities Executables

INFO: Linking 'SQL*Plus 11.2.0.3.0 '
INFO: Linking 'SQL*Plus 11.2.0.3.0 '
INFO: 9/3/13 4:54:07 PM IST: Starting install Link Phase of component SQL*Plus
INFO: Calling Action unixActions10.2.0.3.0  registerForMake
        installMakePath = /usr/bin/make
        installMakeFileName = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/sqlplus/lib/ins_sqlplus.mk
        installTarget = install
        installArguments = ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0
        undoMakeFileName = null
        undoTarget = null
        undoArguments = null
        logFile = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/install/make.log
        progMsg = Linking SQLPLUS Executables

INFO: Linking 'Oracle Programmer 11.2.0.3.0 '
INFO: Linking 'Oracle Programmer 11.2.0.3.0 '
INFO: 9/3/13 4:54:07 PM IST: Starting install Link Phase of component Oracle Programmer
INFO: Linking 'Oracle Internet Directory Client 11.2.0.3.0 '
INFO: Linking 'Oracle Internet Directory Client 11.2.0.3.0 '
INFO: 9/3/13 4:54:07 PM IST: Starting install Link Phase of component Oracle Internet Directory Client
INFO: Calling Action unixActions10.2.0.3.0  registerForMake
        installMakePath = /usr/bin/make
        installMakeFileName = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/ldap/lib/ins_ldap.mk
        installTarget = clientonlyinstall
        installArguments = ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0
        undoMakeFileName = null
        undoTarget = clientonlyinstall
        undoArguments = ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0
        logFile = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/install/make.log
        progMsg = Linking OID Client

INFO: Calling Action unixActions10.2.0.3.0  registerForMake
        installMakePath = /usr/bin/make
        installMakeFileName = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/ldap/lib/ins_ldap.mk
        installTarget = clientonlyinstall
        installArguments = ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0
        undoMakeFileName = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/ldap/lib/ins_ldap.mk
        undoTarget = clientonlyinstall
        undoArguments = ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0
        logFile = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/install/make.log
        progMsg = Linking Client-only Install

INFO: Linking 'SQLJ Runtime 11.2.0.3.0 '
INFO: Linking 'SQLJ Runtime 11.2.0.3.0 '
INFO: 9/3/13 4:54:07 PM IST: Starting install Link Phase of component SQLJ Runtime
INFO: Linking 'Oracle SQLJ 11.2.0.3.0 '
INFO: Linking 'Oracle SQLJ 11.2.0.3.0 '
INFO: 9/3/13 4:54:07 PM IST: Starting install Link Phase of component Oracle SQLJ
INFO: Linking 'Oracle Client 11.2.0.3.0 '
INFO: Linking 'Oracle Client 11.2.0.3.0 '
INFO: 9/3/13 4:54:07 PM IST: Starting install Link Phase of component Oracle Client
INFO: Linking in progress
INFO: Linking in progress
INFO: Link Phase JRE files in Scratch :0
INFO: Calling Action unixActions10.2.0.3.0  make
        registerOnly = false
        installMakePath = /usr/bin/make
        installMakeFileName = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/network/lib/ins_net_client.mk
        installTarget = mkldflags ntcontab.o nnfgt.o
        undoMakeFileName =
        installArguments = ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0
        logFile = /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/install/make.log
        undoTarget =
        progMsg = Linking ldflags Executables

INFO: Linking ldflags Executables
INFO: Linking ldflags Executables
INFO: The output of this make operation is also available at: '/home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/install/make.log'
INFO:

INFO: Start output from spawned process:
INFO: ----------------------------------
INFO:

INFO: rm -f ntcontab.*

INFO: (if [ "compile" = "compile" ] ; then \
          /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/bin/gennttab > ntcontab.c ;\
          /usr/bin/gcc -m32  -m32  -fPIC -c ntcontab.c ;\
          rm -f /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/lib/ntcontab.o ;\
          mv ntcontab.o /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/lib/ ;\
          /usr/bin/ar rv /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/lib/libn11.a /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/lib/ntcontab.o ; fi)

INFO: /bin/sh: line 2: /usr/bin/gcc: No such file or directory

INFO: mv: cannot stat `ntcontab.o'
INFO: : No such file or directory

INFO: /usr/bin/ar: /home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/lib/ntcontab.o: No such file or directory

INFO: make: *** [ntcontab.o] Error 1

INFO: End output from spawned process.
INFO: ----------------------------------
INFO: Exception thrown from action: make
Exception Name: MakefileException
Exception String: Error in invoking target 'mkldflags ntcontab.o nnfgt.o' of makefile '/home/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/network/lib/ins_net_client.mk'. See '/home/oracle/oraInventory/logs/installActions2013-09-03_04-52-05PM.log' for details.
Exception Severity: 1
INFO: Adding ExitStatus STOP_INSTALL to the exit status set
INFO: Finding the most appropriate exit status for the current application
INFO: Exit Status is -4
INFO: Shutdown Oracle Client Installer
```

What is the solution for this error?

Comment: What does the log file that the error pointed you to say?

Comment: I don't see `make` in your package list. Did you omit the last part of the list?

Comment: Have you check the log file? INFO: /bin/sh: line 2: /usr/bin/gcc: No such file or directory. where is the gcc binary?

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the system as root, and do the following:

1. Move the existing /usr/bin/gcc file to /usr/bin/gcc.orig with the mv command:
   mv /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc.orig
2. Using a text editor such as vi, create a new file called gcc41 that contains the following
   content (the line beginning with exec must be a single line):

   ```
    #!/bin/sh
    exec /usr/bin/gcc.orig -m32 -static-libgcc -B /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/32/ $*
   ```

Note:
The directory usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/32/ may differ slightly
depending on the version of your Linux operating system. Search for the
corresponding 32-bit directory under /usr/lib/gcc on your Linux operating
system and use that directory in the gcc41 file.

3. Change the file permission for the gcc41 file using the following command:

   ```
   chmod 755 /usr/bin/gcc41 
   chmod 755 /usr/bin/gcc
   ```
4. Create a symbolic link to /usr/bin/gcc with the following command:
   ln -s -f /usr/bin/gcc41 /usr/bin/gcc
5. Exit as the root user